# Given two sheets with data, I want to show differences on a third sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to compare two sheets and highlight the differences with red and yellow colors on the second sheet. I would like to be able to copy the second sheet over into a third sheet and have the highlighting done there so my first and second source sheets remain untouched.

I attempted creating a third sheet and trying to copy using .copy but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share the code you tried to create a third sheet? Use [`Worksheets.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets.add).

Comment: Where would I put that? Here's what I tried earlier:

Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Worksheets("Sheet3")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are happy with your actual code just add the third sheet to show the color highlights:

```
Sub checked()
    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim shtSheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim shtSheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim shtSheet3 As Worksheet

    Set shtSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set shtSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set shtSheet3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For Each mycell In .UsedRange
            If Not mycell.Value = shtSheet1.Range(mycell.Address).Value Then
                shtSheet3.Cells(1, mycell.Column).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
            If Not mycell.Value = shtSheet1.Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then
                shtSheet3.Range(mycell.Address).Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Michal. This is great- it works. However, I have to manually copy the second sheet over and rename to Sheet3. Is there a way to automatically copy "Sheet2" and name it "Sheet3" when the module is run?

Answer (score 0):

## Highlight Differences

### Highlights

> - Create a copy of second worksheet.
> - Rename the new worksheet.
> - Calculate the used range (Not UsedRange).
> - Create unions of ranges for yellow and red.
> - Apply formats to unions of ranges.

### The Code

```
Sub HighDiff()

  Const cVntWs1 As Variant = "Sheet1"       ' First Worksheet Name/Index
  Const cVntWs2 As Variant = "Sheet2"       ' Second Worksheet Name/Index
  Const cStrWsDiff As String = "Diff"       ' Diff Worksheet Name

  Dim URng As Range                         ' Used Range (Second Worksheet)
  Dim uCell As Range                        ' Range Control Variable
  Dim URng1 As Range                        ' First Union of Ranges
  Dim URng2 As Range                        ' Second Union of Ranges

  ' Create a copy of Second Worksheet (Diff Worksheet)
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cVntWs2).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cVntWs2)

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cVntWs2).Index + 1)

    ' Rename Diff Worksheet.
    .Name = cStrWsDiff

    ' Calculate the used range (Not UsedRange) in Diff Worksheet.
    If Not .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), -4123, , 1) _
        Is Nothing Then Set URng = .Range(.Cells(.Cells.Find("*", _
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).Row, .Cells.Find("*", _
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), , , 2).Column), .Cells(.Cells _
        .Find("*", , , , 1, 2).Row, .Cells.Find("*", , , , 2, 2).Column))

    ' Create unions of ranges.
    For Each uCell In URng
      If uCell.Value <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cVntWs1) _
          .Cells(uCell.Row, uCell.Column).Value Then
        If Not URng1 Is Nothing Then
          Set URng1 = Union(URng1, .Cells(1, uCell.Column))
          Set URng2 = Union(URng2, .Cells(uCell.Row, uCell.Column))
         Else
          Set URng1 = .Cells(1, uCell.Column)
          Set URng2 = .Cells(uCell.Row, uCell.Column)
        End If
      End If
    Next

    ' Apply formatting to unions of ranges.
    URng1.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    URng2.Interior.Color = vbRed

  End With

  ' Release object references.
  Set URng2 = Nothing
  Set URng1 = Nothing
  Set uCell = Nothing
  Set URng = Nothing

End Sub
```